# Cookie not being detected in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, detect

I am setting up a simple mobile/desktop redirect using the technique from [this page](http://www.squidoo.com/php-mobile-redirect). I am also setting a cookie on the mobile site so that if the user wants to link back to the desktop site, that cookie will be read and the redirect will **not** take place. I am dealing with Wordpress sites and while the redirect **does** work, the cookie is **not** working properly. Here is what is happening:

- Mobile redirect **does** work
- Cookie **is successfully set** (confirmed with a test page outside WP)
- When the user clicks back to the desktop site, the cookie isn't **not** being seen and the user gets dumped back to the mobile site again.

I tested my code using 2 external static pages, and everything works 100%. Just not when I use the same exact code in Wordpress. Here is my code from the header.php files on each site:

**Desktop site**

```
<?php
    include('Mobile_Detect.php');
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ( $detect->isMobile() && isset($_COOKIE["mobile"]) ) {
         $detect = "false";
    }
    else if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
         header("Location:http://m.example.com");
    }
?>
```

**Mobile site**

```
<?php setcookie('mobile','m', time()+3600, '/','.example.com'); ?>
```

The PHP code is the **first** thing in the file, before any HTML and there is no errant whitespace before or after it. I've tested this code by echoing some text and the script **is** there and doing what it should. It's just that one problem of the cookie not being seen and stopping the redirect to the mobile site like it should.

After many hours, I need some help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The desktop site, running Drupal, was the problem. It's a caching issue or something, because if I run cron, the whole detection scheme works perfectly. The second time around, it doesn't. It only works one time right after running cron. I'm going to have to get our resident Drupal pro to figure it out.

Thanks for all the help, though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the cookie on the same page, assign the cookie value to a variable. ie:

```
$cookievalue = "m";
setcookie("mobile",$cookievalue);
```

Then, later in the page, you can do:

```
if ( $detect->isMobile() && $cookievalue == "m" ) {
      $detect = "false";
}
else if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
     header("Location:http://m.example.com");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, John. But I'm dealing with two different sites.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine - unless you've got any problems in your Mobile_Detect, but I can't see how considering the cookie is as you said, being set.

I would hazard a guess that you might be looking at an issue on mobile browsers, or possibly privacy settings. Instead of just setting a standard cookie, try using a Session - this would pretty much do all the cookie work for you anyway.

Just use (at the very start of your code, no html etc, as you would with a standard cookie);

```
Session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION["mobile"]) ) {
```

You don't really need to run the detect on that bit of code - the cookie/session array wouldn't be holding a "mobile" index if it wasn't already picked up on.

So instead of;

```
<?php setcookie('mobile','m', time()+3600, '/','.example.com'); ?>
```

Use;

```
<?php
Session_start();
$_SESSION['mobile'] = (bool) true;
$_SESSION['m'] = (bool) true;
$_SESSION['time'] = (int) time()+3600;
```

etc etc..
(Remember that Session_start(); needs to be at the start of every page that will use this cookie!)

It's generally good practice to tie your cookies via browser session, and I'd imagine this would assist with any browser security issue that may be popping up.

Give this a shot and let me know if it works out for you.

Best of luck,

- Eoghan

Comment: Thanks Eoghan. This technique works when I test it using two static pages, but once again Wordpress is not cooperating. Here is my test: [http://clients.flingodesign.com/mobile-test/](http://clients.flingodesign.com/mobile-test/)

The redirect works on mobile devices, but the session to stop the redirect when linking back to the desktop site is not. There must be a simple explaination and it has to be Wordpress based. I don't want to use any plugins or "heavier" solutions. This seemed the best way but perhaps not?